# Remove whitespaces from the end of a textfield in swift

Tags: swift5

I have an email `textfield` which comes while registration of the user. If I add a space at the end of the `email` I am unable to register the user.
How can I remove the space at the end?
Eg: `abc@gmail.com+space` this space should be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this:

```
email.text! = email.text!.replacingOccurencesOf(" ", withString: "")
```

or:

```
let string = textField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
```

or:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool {
       if range.location == 0 && string == " " {
           return false
       }
       return true
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let verifiedEmailString = emailString.replacingOccurencesOf(of:" ", with: "")
```

UPDATE:

Implement UITextFields Delegate method like this:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let cs = Character(" ")
    let filtered = string.components(separatedBy: cs).joined(separator: "")

    return (string == filtered)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this common method in your helper class:**

Description:

```
func trimWhiteSpace(str: String) -> String {
 let trimmedString = str.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespaces)
 return trimmedString
}
```

Usage:

```
let string = trimWhiteSpaceNew(str: textfield.text)
```